# Sort Events by Venue Title - Sort Post set by related post ids

Tags: posts, query, query-posts

In wordpress, I am using The Events Calendar Plugin to host events.  This includes two post types: events and venues.

On an index page, I would like to list ALL events, but ordered by their respective Venue in alphabetical order.

Right now, I grab all events, and sort them by Venue ID (because this is stored in the meta table and easily accessible:

```
<?php global $query_string;
$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => '_EventVenueID',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
$posts = query_posts($args);
?>
```

This works, but obviously, it's not alphabetical.

Is there a way to query the DB to order the events by venue title?  Both the event and the venue are post types.  Something like this:

```
<?php global $query_string;
$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => '_EventVenueID',
--Grab Venue post.title by Event _EventVenueID = post.ID
        'orderby' => 'Venue post.title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );
$posts = query_posts($args);
?>
```

It seems like I would end up with a result that contains two post.ID fields.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Who knows what is actual query by event manger plugin and you are using problematic query_posts!

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta__value in orderby e.g.

```
'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'AND',
 'event_title' => array(
  'key' => 'post.title',
 ),
 'event_id' => array(
  'key' => 'EventVenueID',
 ), 
),
'orderby' => 'event_title',
```

Not tested but should work, this was introduced in 4.2 of WP - https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately.  Possible that this doesn't work correctly using query_posts?  Here's my full code now:
`global $query_string;
$args = array (
 'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'AND',
  'event_title' => array(
   'key' => 'post.title',
  ),
  'event_id' => array(
   'key' => 'EventVenueID',
  ), 
 ),
 'orderby' => 'event_title',
);
$posts = query_posts($args);`

Comment: use wp_query instead

Comment: hmm, no luck with wp_query either